# Wann schreibt man Zahlen aus?

Tags: style, numbers

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   [When does one write numbers with words, when with figures (e.g. "drei" statt "3")?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6748/when-does-one-write-numbers-with-words-when-with-figures-e-g-drei-statt-3)

Es scheint, dass man (in einem nicht-akademischen Kontext) nur kleine Zahlen mit Buchstaben ausschreibt. Wo liegt die Grenze? Hängt es vom Kontext ab?

> Ich habe drei Hunde und 24 Spinnen.

Comment: Ober! `Zahlen!` <- ausgeschrieben. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Die Regel, dass man Zahlen bis zwölf ausschreibt, ist eine alte Buchdruckerregel, die heute zwar nicht mehr gilt, die man aber ruhigen Gewissens als Faustregel weiterhin befolgen kann.

Man kann aber auch unproblematisch größere Zahlen ausschreiben, was insbesondere in erzählenden Texten wie Romanen geschieht. Als klassisches Beispiel sei hier der einundelfzigste Geburtstag von Bilbo Beutlin genannt. Hier ist eine gewisse Subjektivität relevant: Die Zahl sollte ausgeschrieben noch einigermaßen übersichtlich sein. Bei Gedichten (oder Musik) wird häufig ausgeschrieben, weil man dann am Text die Silben, die relevant für das Versmaß sind, erkennen kann.

Zahlen bis zwölf schreibt man aber mitunter auch als Ziffern, wenn man die Zahl betonen will, zum Beispiel in einem technischen Kontext. Maßangaben werden grundsätzlich als Ziffern geschrieben, sofern als Einheit ein Symbol bzw. eine Abkürzung verwendet wird - bei ausgeschriebenen Maßangaben kann man wiederum ausschreiben (z. B: 2/zwei Euro, aber: 2 EUR).

Comment: Das Wort „einhundertelfzig“ kann man aber auch schwer mit Ziffern ausdrücken. :)

Comment: *einundelfzigste*? Ist das oben ein Tippfehler oder gibt es in Mittelerde ein eigenes Zahlensystem? 111. = einhundertelfte

Comment: @splattne Das ist die Übersetzung von „eleventy-first“ (also eigentlich „elfzig-erste“). Das wäre eigentlich viel sinnvoller (schließlich sagt man auch oft neunzehnhundert statt eintausendneunhundert) aber es klingt wohl so ungewohnt, dass sich der Übersetzer anders entschieden hat …. Um Deine Frage zu beantworten: nein, Mittelerde hat kein eigenes Zahlensystem im eigentlichen Sinn, Tolkien hat lediglich das existierende System für Jahreszahlen logisch weitergeführt.

Comment: @Konrad_Rudolph danke für die Antwort. Um etwas Haarspalterei zu betreiben: "der einundelfzigste Geburtstag" ist allerdings keine Jahreszahl.

Comment: Ich glaube, mit der Einundelfzig betont man die Tatsache des für Hobbits doch erstaunlich hohen Alters, für das die kleinen Leute keine richtigen Worte haben. Und dass es so übersetzt wurde, naja, wenn twenty-first einundzwanzig ist, ist es doch logisch, dass eleventy-first einundelfzig ist, oder? :)

Comment: Eleventy-first zeigt einfach wie "seltsam" die Hobbits sind.  Und dass man das dann ausschreibt hat nix mit irgendwelchen "bis N schreibt immer aus" Regeln zu tun, sondern schlicht damit, dass man es, wie @Debilski richtig sagt, nicht einfach als "111" schreiben kann :D

Comment: Allerdings werden im selben Buch auch diverse andere Altersangaben ausgeschrieben, unter anderem der *hundertzwölfte* (ich habe mir jetzt gespart, *alle* anderen Angaben herauszusuchen).

Comment: Klassischer Fall: »Ich brauche Briefmarken. siebzehn Stück à 10 Cent und sieben Stück à 20 Cent.«

Answer (score 7):

Um mich den Vorrednern anzuschließen, die Schreibweise von Zahlen ist insofern vom Kontext abhängig, als dass ihre Schreibweise die Bedeutung stützen soll. Wird eine Zahl also zur Verdeutlichung statistischer oder mathematischer Umstände gebraucht, so ist die Schreibweise als Zahl vorzuziehen. Andernfalls darf freimütig ausgeschrieben werden.

Ich verweise auf den entsprechenden Duden-Artikel: http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/schreibung-von-zahlen

Answer (score 6):

Als Zusatz zu den Antworten von @OregonGhost und @TheBlastOne:

In einem eher erzählenden Prosa- oder Gedichtkontext kann es in Ordnung sein, auch größere Zahlen auszuschreiben. Man könnte in einem Gedicht, einem Liedtext oder einem Kinderbuch durchaus folgende Formulierungen antreffen:

> Ich habe drei Hunde und vierundzwanzig Spinnen

oder

> Die Autoreparatur kostete mich fünfhundert Euro.

oder

> Ich habe tausend Tränen geweint

allzu komplexe Ausschreibungen wie "dreihundertvierundachtzig", die nicht mehr vernünftig lesbar sind, werden aber nur als spezielles künstlerisches Stilmittel verwendet.

Blind ergoogeltes [Beispiel](http://books.google.de/books?id=wfsCxsv3bOcC&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=Einhundertf%C3%BCnfundsiebzig%20paragraph&source=bl&ots=4BbioPDvbi&sig=oQ79F-bIYQWTuFIYRUOOApF97bw&hl=en&ei=mQnoTbPNI9CeOrrEueAJ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> »Warum musst Du ausgerechnet in der fünften Etage wohnen, Camilla? Sechsundsechzig Stufen! Aber immerhin besser als fünfundsiebzig oder einhundertfünfundsiebzig wie der Paragraf.«

Comment: ja in der Kunst ist alles erlaubt ;)

Comment: Nicht nur in einem *sehr informellen* Kontext: Ausschreiben von Zahlen ist grundsätzlich in Ordnung, wird aber in akademischen/technischen Kontexten sehr selten und in erzählenden häufig verwendet.

Comment: @Oregon das ist die bessere Formulierung, bearbeitet. Danke!

Comment: +1 für die Erwähnung der Ausschreibung komplexer Zahlen als Stilmittel.

Answer (score 2):

In der Schule habe ich gelernt, dass Zahlen bis zwölf auszuschreiben sind, und ab 13 nicht mehr. Anscheinend kontextunabhängig.

Comment: Allerdings würde ich Hundert nicht als 100 schreiben...mh...

Answer (score 1):

Ich habe zwanzig 5-Euro-Münzen zusammengerollt, und dem Zuhälter damit eine über seine Jacketkronen gezogen.

```
Ich habe zwanzig 5-Euro-Münzen …
Ich habe zwanzig Fünf-Euro-Münzen …
Ich habe 20 Fünf-Euro-Münzen …
Ich habe 20 5-Euro-Münzen …
```

Die 20 als größere Zahl dürfte verzahlt werden, während die 5 als kl. Zahl geschrieben werden könnte, aber die Einheit gebietet eher eine Verzifferung der Fünf, so dass die 20 5 schlecht lesbar wäre, was dann dazu führt, dass man die 20 lieber ausschreibt.

Notiz am Rande: Da der standardisierte Europäer als Tausender-Trennzeichen den Punkt (18.000,00 €) verwendet, und der Ami und Brite das Komma (20,000.00 $), entwickelte sich als Kompromiss eine Leerstelle als atlantikübergreifende Konvention: 19 000. Dies bringt aber das neue Problem mit sich, dass man dort einen Zeilenumbruch sich ungewollt einhandeln kann, so man einfache Blanks verwendet. Wenn ich nun von 13 200-Euronoten spreche, so ist oben konstruiertes Problem perfekt. Dreizehn 200-Euronoten dagegen lassen sich gut lesen. Bei 17 500 Noten dieser Stückelung, in Worten: siebzehntausendfünfhundert 200-Euronoten, wird es langsam lästig, aber da kann man sich ja eine Sekretärin leisten, die 350 Anschläge die Minute schafft.

Elf Euro neunundneunzig ist übrigens weniger als 12, darf aber dennoch als 11,99 Euro geschrieben werden. Die 24 dagegen kann – je nach Kontext – auch als zwo Dutzend paraphrasiert werden.

Comment: Für das Problem der Leerstelle die nicht von einem Zeilenumbruch ersetzt werden soll, hat TeX schlauerweise die ~.  K.A. was man da z.B. bei MS Word machen kann... (ist auch nicht nur bei Zahlen ein Problem: "Mr. Smith" oder "Herr Meier" liest sich nicht so schön wenn von einem Umbruch unterbrochen)

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard Geschütztes Leerzeichen. Tastatureingabe unter Windoof mit gedrückter Alt-Taste und auf dem Ziffernblock 0160. Unter OpenOffice geht mE auch Steuerung-Umschalt-Leertaste.

Answer (score 0):

Als Mathematiker schreibe ich Zahlen selten aus.

Ich würde

> Ich habe 3 Hunde und 24 Spinnen.

schreiben, da das teilweise Ausschreiben auf mich völlig unlogisch wirkt.

In fortlaufendem Text, schreibe ich einzelne Zahlen bis zehn schon mal aus.

Comment: Mathematiker sind eben keine normalen Menschen... ;-)