# How to write ordinal numbers in German?

Tags: numbers

How do Germans write Ordinal numbers as in English?

> 1st, 2nd, 3rd ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We suffix the numbers with a dot:

1., 2., 3., ...

This is also the reason we write dates as 19.8.2011 ("der neunzehnte achte zweitausendelf").

Comment: Do you put the dot there even when it's succeeded by a comma?

Comment: +1 for giving the reason for writing dates with dots. Never thought about that. @Tim N: Yes.

Comment: @Tim N Without the dot it would be "eins zwei drei", so I'd rather leave out the comma.  But normally this isn't an issue.

Answer (score 13):

In a written text a number followed by a dot is fine for a date

> Wir kommen am 7. September vorbei.

However in another context it may be better to write out the ordinal numbers with rules following those for [numbers in general](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/895/23).

> Wir haben die siebte Ausfahrt nicht gefunden und uns verirrt.
>   Der Urgroßvater lädt zum hundertsten Geburtstag ein.

In writing a number is usually suffixed by *"-te"* but there are exceptions:

> 1. **erste**
> 2. zweite
> 3. **dritte**
> 4. vierte
> 5. fünfte
> 6. sechste
> 7. **siebte** (der [siebente](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2207/siebte-or-siebente))
> 8. achte
> 9. neunte
> 10. zehnte
> 11. elfte
> 12. zwölfte
> 13. dreizehnte
>       [...]
> 14. zwanzigste
> 15. dreißigste
>       [...]
> 16. [ein]hundertste