# "Siebte" or "Siebente"?

Tags: numbers

I saw both "siebente" and "siebte" for *7th*, does it have two versions?

If so, what's the difference?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only ordinal number where two valid variations exist is "*der siebte*" and its more antiquated variant "*der siebente*":

[image]

This rule applies for all numbers counting with seven

> (107.) *einhundertundsiebente* vs. *einhundertsiebte* (the *und* can also be omitted).

Comment: Wow, this graph illustrates brilliantly just what I suspected.

Comment: Yeah, I was impressed too. Sometimes these Ngrams are not so bad.

Comment: Is the crossing at about '77, maybe on the 7.7. accidentally?

Comment: Hundertste - Einhunderste, Zwölfte - Dutzendste, Tausendste - Eintausendste (usw), Fünfzigste - Fuffzichste.

Comment: @User unknown: "Hundertste/Einhunderste" and "Tausendste/Eintausendste" are not the same as siebente/siebte.

Comment: I didn't want to express, that they are an identic pattern, but that the statement 'The only ordinal number where two valid variations exist' is wrong. There are other ordinal numbers, where variations exist. Maybe you improve the statement with '... where *this* variation exists.'

Comment: @userunknown: To be more precise, for "sieben" it's a variation that exists *only* in the ordinal number and is not just taken over from the cardinal number.

Answer (score 3):

The proper answer is: it depends. On the region, age and speaker.

The correct version still is "siebente", but as already mentioned the tendency goes to the shortened version "siebte" today which arose from the Ruhr area dominating German media.

There is also a discrepancy between the former eastern part of Germany and former western part of Germany:

http://mediawiki.ids-mannheim.de/VarGra/index.php/Siebente_/_siebte

People in the eastern part still use the proper version "siebente" more frequently. And actually they are right because the word "siebte" is not the ordinal number seven, "er/sie siebte" is the simple past of the verb "sieben".

https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sieben_filtern_sichten_aussondern
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sieben

Comment: "Siebte" klingt für mich ziemlich bescheuert, als ob es mit einem Sieb zu tun hat. Ganz klar "Siebente", denn es kommt ja von Sieben. ;)  (aus der mitteldeutschen Sicht)

Answer (score 0):

"siebente" is very formal and pronounced, normal is "siebte".

Comment: *normal is "siebte".* - no, that is true only in some parts of Germany. In Berlin, for example, the normal pronounciation of "siebente" is *siemte* (in a similar mechanism that in colloquial speech turns "haben" into "ham").

Comment: that's not quite true, there's a longer restriction of the nasal pathway or maybe other little peculiarities that are hardly audible but distinct from a mere /zi:mte/ that the orthography cannot capture.