# When does one write numbers with words, when with figures (e.g. "drei" statt "3")?

Tags: spelling, numbers

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   [Wann schreibt man Zahlen aus?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/895/wann-schreibt-man-zahlen-aus)?

Assuming it is not completely irrelevant, when does one write the numbers with words?

> *Sie isst drei Äpfel*

or

> *Sie isst 3 Äpfel.*

Assuming that there is a rule, is it just an aesthetics issue? Or is it absolutely mandatory to follow it?

Comment: There's a rule of thumb: numbers 1 to 12 as words, everything equals or higher than 13 as numbers. - In the end, it's completely up to you.

Comment: "Sie isst 3 Äpfel" looks very strange (if it's not meant to be a scientific text, as pointed out below). 99% of the time you'd write "drei".

Comment: @Em1 Und was sagt die Regel über 12,5 Äpfel? ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer strongly depends of the intended accuracy, the nature of the numbers and the type of text. My private rule of thumb is the following:

For **scientific texts, manuals, etc.**, I would write out 1 to 12, if they are natural numbers (in contrast to real numbers), and nothing else.

> Seien *a* und *b* zwei Elemente der Menge *X*. – Let *a* and *b* be two elements of the set *X*. (Natural number)
>
> Die Probe wurde 5 Stunden gekühlt. – The sample was cooled for 5 hours. (Real number)

However, I would not write out cardinal numbers that refer to an enumeration system:

> In Kapitel 5 … (cardinal number, enumeration system)
>   Aber: Im fünften Kapitel … (ordinal number, enumeration system)
>
> Das Elektron hat die Nebenquantenzahl 2. (cardinal number, enumeration system)

Finally, I would not write out any natural numbers that are followed by an abbreviated unit:

> Die Schlüsselgröße ist 8 B.
>   Aber: Der Schlüssel ist acht Byte groß.

In **stories, poems, etc.** I would additionally write out 1, 1.5 and 2 to 12 as well as 20, 30, …, 100, 200, …, 1000, …, if they are vague information. As a rule of thumb for everything beyond 12: If *x* could be replaced by *x+1* (ignoring the correctness of the information), do not write *x* out.

> Er ist ungefähr dreißig Jahre alt. – He is about thirty years old.
>   (His actual age can be something between, e.g., 25 and 35. *thirty-one* would not work, since it is too accurate for the intended vagueness.)
>
> Er ist 30 Jahre alt. – He is 30 years old.
>   (He is exactly 30 years old. If he were 31 years old, you would write “31 years”; so 31 would work as well.)
>
> Sie gingen anderthalb Kilometer. – They walked one and a half kilometers.
>   (Vague information – they walked something between 1.25 and 1.75 kilometers, and even that may be only the best guess.)
>
> Sie gingen 1,5 km. – They walked 1.5 km.
>   (Accurate information – They walked something between 1.45 km and 1.55 km and this is certain. Of course, you usually do need such an accuracy in this kind of text.)

**In both cases**, the style should not switch in the middle of a list or similar:

> Fahrzeuge mit 6 bis 23 Sitzen. – Vehicles with 6 to 23 seats.

Comment: I like the *"x+1"* rule a lot, never heard of it but it does make sense.

Comment: The reasoning behind the switch at 12/13 is that numbers up to 12 have their own “names” in German, whereas higher numbers are composed: “zwölf”, but “drei-zehn”.

Comment: There's missing one important thing in your answer: While "2" is always "zwei", and "3" ist always "drei" etc., the number "1" is not always "eins" but also "ein", "einen", ... "Sie gingen 1 km" - "Er hält sich 3 Hunde, 2 Katzen und 1 Wellensittich". Technically speaking this is wrong. In respect to stylistic it's disputable. For informal texts it may be OK but you should at least aware of that. Exceptions: 1 Jahr; 1.1.1111; 1€; 1111%

Comment: @Em1: Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob ich verstanden haben, worauf Du hinaus willst. Dass die Zahl eins stärker dekliniert wird als die anderen, beeinflusst meine Antwort doch nicht. Niemand hat etwas davon gesagt, dass 1 immer „eins“ auszusprechen ist.

Comment: Eben dass du gar nicht darauf eingehst, erwähne ich das.  In einer flüchtigen Email ist's vielleicht noch OK, aber "1" steht eigentlich für "eins" und nicht für "eine" oder "einen", somit ist es - wenn man pedantisch vorgeht - falsch. Ich würde es wahrscheinlich nie als falsch ankreiden, aber zumindest sollte man das ins Bewusstsein rufen, so dass man dann für sich selbst entscheidet, wie man damit umgeht.

Comment: In einer Masterarbeit würde ich z.b. schreiben: "Von den 77 Schnittstellen musste ich nur eines implementieren." "Siebenundsiebzig" ist zu unleserlich, "1" ist nicht "richtig genug", also breche ich deinen Styleguide, es nicht zu mischen. Auch wenn ich sonst dem Styleguide zustimme und ihn genauso handhabe.

Comment: Ich verstehe, aber sehe das anders. Ich sehe keinen Grund, dass 1 strikt durch *eins* zu ersetzen wäre, und habe deswegen kein Problem damit, 1 für *eine* o. Ä. zu schreiben – genausowenig wie ich ein Problem damit habe 101 für *hundenderteinen* o. Ä. zu schreiben (wobei hier natürlich auch immer *hunderteins* stehen könnte).

Comment: The part about scientific texts is partially wrong. A quantity with units (zu Deutsch „Größe“) is always written with Numerals and the unit symbol. Furthermore, the criterion shouldn't be, if it's a natural number but if it is used to describe a fixed quantity (even without units).

Comment: @Toscho: The only scientific units that I am aware of and that are not preceeded by real numbers are units of information (such as bit), where I would stand by my private rule of thumb. What do you mean by “fixed quantity”?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Electric charges are multiples of the elementary charge `e`, so if you use `e` as a unit, the electrical charge is always preceeded by an integer. Furthermore, quantum numbers are integers, half integers or even natural numbers.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft By „fixed quantity“ I mean a somehow defined quantity with a special meaning rather than just being the cardinality of a set. Example: In „Seien a und b zwei Elemente …“ the `zwei` is just the cardinality of the subset `{a,b}` and has no other meaning. In „Dieses Elektron hat die Quantenzahlen 2, 1, -1, 1/2.“ all numbers have a special meaning: the respective quantum number.

Comment: @Toscho: These are indeed examples, for which I would deviate from my rule of thumb as given here (though I would write out a sufficiently small number before “Elementarladungen” in a rare case where it is unabbreviated). However, I do not think that “special meaning” or “fixed quantity” are good criteria. I am going to add something that should cover these (and some more) cases.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft As elementary charges are fixed to elementary particles, it would indeed be correct to write `zwölf Elementarladungen` for a set of twelve protons, e.g. a magnesium core, as it is a cardinality. If positive and negative particles are mixed, even the total charge is less than 13 e, this is inappropriate again, as negative numbers aren't cardinalities.

Comment: Your rules seem inconsistent if you write *5 Stunden* (as opposed to *fünf Stunden* vs. *5 h*) … but that’s really the only nitpick I have ;)

Comment: @Jan: I do not quite follow. Just that I do not write out anything with an abbreviated unit does not mean that I do write out everything without an abbreviated unit.

Answer (score 5):

Richtig ist, dass kleine Zahlen bis 12 ausgeschrieben werden, aber es gibt Ausnahmen, nämlich wenn sie in einem technischen/mathematischen Kontext vorkommen und wenn sie mit einer Einheit vesehen sind:

> Im Januar war es hier 9°C kalt.
>
> Der elektrische Rollstuhl fährt 7 km/h.

Bei Namensbestandteilen wird die Zahl römisch geschrieben:

> Karl IV traf Brutalius XXIII.

Im Datum werden auch kleine Zahlen durch Ziffern ausgedrückt:

> Am 8.7. endet die WM.

Comment: Guter Hinweis mit den Namenszahlen, aber deine Beispiel der Datumsangabe widerspricht ISO 8601.

Comment: @Toscho: Was sagt denn ISO 8601? Und wer muss die benutzen?

Comment: ISO 8601 besagt, dass numerische Datumsangaben im Format YYYY-MM-TT zu erfolgen haben. Sie ist internationaler Standard und in Deutschland/Europa durch DIN bzw. EN umgesetzt.

Comment: @Toscho: Danke. Teil 2 der Frage war, für wen diese Norm verbindlich ist.

Comment: Niemand *muss* sie benutzen. Steht weder im Grundgesetz noch im Strafgesetzbuch. Jeder *soll* sie benutzen. Dafür hat man Standards ja schließlich.

Comment: @Toscho: Deine Empfehlung wird von Wikipedia nicht gedeckt. Demnach handelt es sich um eine Norm für Datenaustausch in Wirtschaft und Wissenschaft, und passt erkennbar nicht auf mein Beispiel.

Answer (score 2):

I would write mostly digits (also in other languages), except when you have tow consecutive numbers in a sentence. In that case I write one (mostly the first one) in words, so that the reader knows they're two separate numbers:

> Der Mikrocomputer hat **acht 32-bit** Register.

rather than

> Der Mikrocomputer hat **8 32-bit** Register.

Answer (score 2):

There is a rule: Natural numbers from one to twelve are written as words. It goes back to the former common usage of the duodecimal system. (Compare: dozen; feet and inch)

However there are some special cases as noted in other answers to your question. If you use words in general you have to write these numbers as words, if not you write them as digits (*drei Kilogramm*, *3 kg*).