# Nummerierung im Text

Tags: numbers

Welche der folgenden Schreibweisen ist richtig?

```
A) Das 8. Bit wird gesetzt.
B) Das 8te Bit wird gesetzt.
C) Das 8-te Bit wird gesetzt.
D) Das achte Bit wird gesetzt.
```

Im Duden habe ich folgendes gefunden:

> Eine früher gültige Buchdruckerregel, nach der generell die Zahlen von 1 bis 12 in Buchstaben und die Zahlen ab 13 in Ziffern zu schreiben sind, gilt heute nicht mehr!
>
> [...]
>
> Die Zahlen von 1 bis 12 werden überwiegend dann in Ziffern geschrieben, wenn sie  z. B. in Statistiken oder wissenschaftlichen Texten  zusammen mit dem dazugehörigen Substantiv die Aufmerksamkeit auf sich lenken sollen

Quelle: [Duden.de](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/schreibung-von-zahlen)

So wurde das auch hier gesagt: [Wann schreibt man Zahlen aus?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/895/wann-schreibt-man-zahlen-aus)

Also vermutlich nicht `D)`.

### Weitere Beispielsätze

```
I) Der Entwurf eines n-ten Dualzählers läuft analog.
II) Ein 16ter Baustein ist im Entwurf.
```

Comment: Noch [eine weitere Frage](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6748/when-does-one-write-numbers-with-words-when-with-figures-e-g-drei-statt-3) zum Ausschreiben von Zahlen …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A und D sind die üblichen Schreibweisen. Welche man wählt, ist eine Stilfrage; dazu gibt es die verlinkten Fragen über das Ausschreiben von Zahlen.

B ist ungebräuchlich, aber wohl nicht falsch.

C entspricht nicht der Amtlichen Regelung (2006), wegen § 41:

> Vor Suffixen setzt man nur dann einen Bindestrich, wenn sie mit einem Einzelbuchstaben verbunden werden.

*Das n-te Bit* wäre daher korrekt.

Comment: Argh, ich habe irgendwie § 41 übersehen …

Comment: B ist falsch, denn es müsste "8e" heißen, das "t" ist in "acht" doch schon enthalten, oder?

Comment: @Alexander Kosubek: Na ja, eigentlich ist das Suffix schon _-te_, auch wenn das _t_ mit dem Ende von _acht_ verschmilzt. Ich denke, beides würde gehen, aber beides wird in der Praxis kaum verwendet.

Comment: @chirlu Wäre dann umgekehrt auch "20te" in Ordnung? Wenn ein doppeltes "t" ignoriert werden kann, dann doch auch ein fehlendes "s", oder?

Comment: @Alexander Kosubek: Andere Sprachen machen es so. Im Englischen beispielsweise stehen _3rd_ und _5th_ nicht für _threerd_ bzw. _fiveth_, im Italienischen _4º_ nicht für _quattroo_. Genau wie unser Punkt deuten die Suffixe also nur an, wie man die Ziffern interpretieren muß.

Comment: Man könnte es auch machen wie beim Rebus und z.B. _7-en+ter_ schreiben. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Nur dass eine Regel nicht mehr gilt, heißt ja nicht, dass nun das Gegenteil die Regel ist. Variante D ist also weiterhin möglich (und ich würde sie auch in den meisten Kontexten stilistisch bevorzugen).

Ebenso möglich sind Variante A ([Rechtschreibregeln](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf), § 104) und Variante B ([Rechtschreibregeln](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf), § 41).

Comment: Ich dachte das `D` eher nicht in Frage kommt, da es sich um einen wissenschaftlichen Text handelt (den Abschnitt auf Duden.de, auf den ich mich beziehe, habe ich nachgetragen).

Comment: Im konkreten Fall würde man vermutlich _Bit 7_ (bei Zählung von 0) schreiben.

Answer (score -1):

Man beachte auch die DIN 1421, die direkte Aufzählungen behandelt. Diese werden immer mit 1. oder a) gekennzeichnet.

Comment: Allerdings ist der Beispielsatz keine Aufzählung.

Comment: Hab ich auch nie behauptet. Es ist nur ein ähnliches Konstrukt, für das eben nicht nur die deutsche Rechtschreibung gilt.