# Schreibweise von Zahlen im akademischen Kontext

Tags: spelling, numbers

Im Studium schreibe ich eine Arbeit, bei der ich häufig Zahlen verwende. Ich bin mir jedoch unsicher, ob man diese grundsätzlich als Ziffern bzw. Zahlen verwendet oder das ganze Wort ausschreibt.

Beispiele:

- … im Bereich von Null bis Eins …
- … auf Eins normiert …
- Der Wert Null entspricht einem schwarzen Pixel und Eins einem weißen Pixel.

Gibt es dazu allgemein gültige Regeln oder sind dies teilweise auch persönliche Präferenzen?

Comment: Welches Studienfach?

Comment: @PaulFrost Ich studiere Elektro- und Informationstechnik.

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: [When does one write numbers with words, when with figures (e.g. "drei" statt "3")?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/6748/2594)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ja und nein. Es gibt Empfehlungen aber kein absoluten Regeln. Wähle dem Kontext nach angemessen. Ist die Zahl selbst wichtig oder werden sie verglichen oder mit Einheiten versehen, wird sie tendentiell als Zahl geschrieben. Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/zahlen-und-ziffern) meint beispielsweise:

> Zahlen lassen sich mit Ziffern (Zahlzeichen) oder Buchstaben schreiben. Man kann sich hier an die folgenden Empfehlungen halten:
>
> 1. Ein- und zweisilbige Zahlen werden in allgemeinen Texten in Buchstaben gesetzt, längere in Ziffern.
>
>    eins, sieben, zwölf, dreißig, hundert
>    37 (statt: siebenunddreißig)
> 2. Bei Nummern, Jahreszahlen, Maß- und Währungsbezeichnungen und beim Datum werden auch kurze Zahlen in Ziffern gesetzt.
>
>    im Jahr 4 v. Chr.
>    am 2. April
>    12 km, –5 °C
> 3. Kurze Zahlen werden ferner in Ziffern gesetzt, wenn sie mit längeren im gleichen Zusammenhang stehen oder wenn die Zahlen einen
>    hohen Informationswert haben (so in Sportberichten, Inventaren,
>    Tabellen).
>
>    Den Gegnern fehlen noch 23 Punkte, unserem Team nur noch 8 Punkte.
>    (Inventar:) 2 Kabel und 1 Muffe fehlen.

Answer (score 1):

Erstmal (weil viele diese Begriffe verwechseln): Ziffern verhalten sich zu Zahlen wie Buchstaben zu Wörtern. Es gibt 10 Ziffern, jede davon hat auf einer Tastatur eine eigene Taste, und damit kann man Zahlen schreiben.

---

Jetzt zur Frage:

Vor ein paar Jahren hat mir ein Uni-Professor mal folgendes dazu gesagt:

- Grundregel: Zahlen schreibt man mit Ziffern, nicht als Worte (nicht mit Buchstaben). (13, 25, 30, 100)
- Ausnahme 1: Wenn man die Zahl mit nur einer Silbe ausspricht, sollte man sie als Wort (mit Buchstaben) schreiben. (Null, drei, zwölf)
- Ausnahme 2: Die Zahl *sieben* schreibt man ebenfalls als Wort obwohl man sie mit 2 Silben ausspricht.
- Ausnahme von den beiden Ausnahmen: Wenn hinter der Zahl eine Einheit kommt, die abgekürzt geschrieben wird (z.B. 4 kg, 11 m), schreibt man die Zahl mit Ziffern.
- Wenn die Einheit ausgeschrieben wird, und die Zahl nach dem bisher gesagten mit Buchstaben zu schreiben wäre, hat man die Option, sie auch mit Ziffern schreiben. (4 Minuten, neun Jahre)
- Punktestände von Spielen schreibt man immer mit Ziffern (Das Match endete 0:0)
- Zahlen in Tabellen, Listen und tabellenartigen Aufzählungen schreibt man immer mit Ziffern (Auf meinem Tisch befinden sich 3 Bücher, 5 Stifte und 2 leere Kaffeetassen)

Und zum Abschluss kam die wichtigste Regel überhaupt: »Aber nimm das nicht zu streng. Wichtig ist eigentlich nur, dass es der Leser leicht lesen kann.«

Comment: Dass es 10 Ziffern gibt stimmt für Dezimal- und Dualzahlen, nicht jedoch für Oktal- und Hexadezimalzahlen. :)

Comment: @user unknown Im Oktalsystem gibt es acht Ziffern (zwei weniger, als die meisten Menschen Finger haben). Acht schreibt man im Oktalsystem als "10". Analog für das Hexadezimalsystem.