# Wann ist es erlaubt, z.B. „zwanzig hundert“ anstatt „zweitausend“ zu sagen?

Tags: numbers

Ich weiß nur, dass es für Jahre gültig ist,

> neunzehnhundertneunundneunzig

anstatt

> tausendneunhundertneunundneunzig

zu sagen/schreiben. Für Jahre, die größer als 1999 sind, sagt man aber die Nummer, wie man es normalerweise liest.

Ein Bekannter sagte heute, er verdiene „siebzehnhundert“. Obwohl er kein Muttersprachler ist, klingt sein Deutsch gut. Allerdings weiß ich nicht, ob er diese Zahl richtig gesagt hat.  Deswegen stelle ich folgende Frage:

- Für welche Dinge kann man die Zahl [*abcd*] als

> [*ab*]hundert[*cd*]

anstatt

> [*a*]tausend[*b*]hundert[*cd*]

lesen? (wobei *a, b, c, d* = 0, 1, 2, …, 9 und *a* ≠ 0.)

Comment: Erlaubt ist es wohl meistens - üblich ist es nicht immer.

Comment: Gesprochen drehen übrigens i.d.R. c und d, d.h. 1234 wird zu ... vierunddreißig. Bei 1204 fällt die Null aber weg, für elf, zwölf gibt es Sonderformen und Zahlen die auf Null enden weichen auch vom Schema ab.

Comment: in this question only could it be have used "statt" rather than "anstatt" what is difference between two?

Comment: @user1474062: Comments are not for asking new questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Für Jahre gilt, wie teilweise bereits geschrieben:

- Jahreszahlen vor Christi Geburt werden als 'normale' Zahlen ausgesprochen: *[Thutmosis III](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thutmosis_III.). (geboren um tausendvierhundertsechsundachzig v. Chr.)*
- von Christi Geburt bis 1000 stellt sich die Frage nicht
- von 1000 bis 1099 die "tausend[cd]"-Variante: *Die [Schlacht von Hastings](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlacht_von_Hastings) fand am 14. Oktober tausendsechsundsechzig statt*
- von 1100 bis 1999 die Variante mit [ab]hundert[cd]
- nach 2000 die 'korrekte' Zahl.

(In meinen Beispielen habe ich die Zahlen ausgeschrieben, um deren Aussprache zu zeigen. Normalerweise werden die [Zahlen nicht ausgeschrieben](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/895/wann-schreibt-man-zahlen-aus)).

Konkrete Jahreszahlen nach 2050 sind noch nicht praxisrelevant, d. h., es gibt noch keinen allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch. Ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass man für Jahre größer 2099 wieder zu der Hundert-Variante wechselt. Also für 2134 ein *"einundzwanzighundertvierunddreißig"*.

---

Nach meinem Sprachempfinden gilt:

Für Nicht-Jahreszahlen verwendet man die korrekte Zahl als [a]tausend[b]hundert[cd].

Ausnahmen bilden ganze Hunderter, insbesondere wenn es Ungefähr-Werte sind. Die Aussage: *Ich verdiene Siebzehnhundert* heißt nicht, dass er 1700 € verdient, sondern etwa (1700 ± 100) Euro

Comment: "Für Nicht-Jahreszahlen verwendet man die korrekte Zahl als [ab]tausend[cd]." -> Wolltest du sagen, dass man die korrekte Zahl als [a]Tausend[b]Hundert[cd] verwendet?

Comment: @Em1: Dann aber auch cd umkehren, denn 34 wird ja vierundreißig gesprochen - erst die vier, dann die drei. :)

Comment: _zwanzig-fünzehn_ und _zwanzig-fuffzehn_ sind für das laufende Jahr durchaus gebräuchlich, vgl. _Agenda 2010_, und auch für frühere Jahrhunderte, inkl. _zehn-sechsundsechzig_, ist das (wie im Englischen) nicht unüblich. Möglicherweise ist das unter Personen, die viel mit Jahreszahlen operieren und gefühlt nie Zeit haben, gebräuchlicher. Alles mit _?zwanzighundert_ ist hingegen wirklich unüblich, jedoch trotzdem verständlich. Für das aktuelle Jahrhundert, also Jahreszahlen 20xy, habe ich auch schon das kürzere, obgleich seltsame, _zwei-xy_ bzw. _zwo-xy_ gehört.

Comment: Würde ich nicht so verstehen: "Die Aussage: Ich verdiene Siebzehnhundert heißt nicht, dass er 1700 € verdient, sondern etwa (1700 ± 100) Euro"

Comment: Ich würde auch für Jahre zwischen 1000 und 1100 die Kurzform für zulässig erachten (The Battle of Hastings: zehn sechsundsechzig), und auch "zwanzig sechzehn" etc. wird immer populärer, wohl aus dem Englischen kommend. Ich gehe davon aus, dass sich das langfristig durchsetzen wird. Vor allem in der Umgangssprache ist die Verwendung von x hundert für x < 20 durchaus üblich. (fünfzehn hundert, nicht aber einundzwanzig hundert.)

Comment: @Iris: Wohl eher 1700 ± 50 Euro oder 25 Euro. Wobei es nicht symetrisch sein muss. Ein bescheidener Mensch mag bei 1780 auch noch 1700 sagen, aber wer bei 1620 schon 1700 sagt muss wohl ein Aufschneider sein. Auch weiß man nicht, ob jmd. bei 1745 vielleicht Siebzehn-fuffzisch aurunden würde. Je nach dem, wie genau derjenige sein möchte könnte es auch bedeuten <= 1705.

Comment: @userunknown, nein, ich würde prinzipiell nicht davon ausgehen, dass bei einer Gehaltsangabe Siebzehnhundert mehr Varianz zulässt als Eintausendsiebenhundert. Bei beidem erwarte ich keine Gehaltsangabe auf den Euro genau, sondern so wie es die Mathematik vorschreibt ein gerundetes Ergebnis.

Comment: @Iris: Die Mathematik schreibt nicht vor, auf wie viele Stellen zu runden ist - da musst Du Dir andere Verbündete suchen.

Comment: @user unknown, das meinte ich nicht. Ich meinte, dass man im Matheunterricht lernt, dass man 1620, wenn man auf hundert rundet, immer auf 1600 abrundet und nicht auf 1700 auf. Man könnte natürlich auch auf tausend, also auf 2000 runden, aber bei dieser Gehaltsklasse ist das meiner Erfahrung nach eher ungebräuchlich.

Comment: @Iris: Ja, aber das schreibt man dann +/-50, nicht +/-100.

Comment: Diese besondere Art der Ausprache der Zahlen dient dem Einsparen von Silben, weil man zum Zeitpunkt der Entstehung der Kalender und mit fortschreitender Bedeutung von Zeit die Information schnell übermitteln wollte. Weil Tau-send weniger Silben hat als Zehn-hun-dert aber Sieb-zehn-hun-dert weniger als Tausend-sie-ben-hun-dert hat man sich für diese Sprechweise entschieden, auch wenn das nicht festgeschrieben steht. Daher ist es unwahrscheinlich ( aber nicht festgeschrieben ), dass wir jemals dazu zurückkehren, weil Ein-und-zwan-zig-hun-dert viel zu viele Silben hat.