# How to read years in German?

Tags: numbers, time

The year 1995 is read in English **nineteen ninety-five**.

*This means we read the first two digits as a single number and then the next two digits, with the same rule.*

**Is this rule true in German?**

I mean, should we read it as **neunzehn-fünfundneunzig**?

What about 2007?

Comment: Related (in German): http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9069/wann-ist-es-erlaubt-z-b-zwanzig-hundert-anstatt-zweitausend-zu-sagen

Comment: Your German year is 1999, not 1995.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In German generally (i.e. not just in Germany but also in Austria and in Switzerland), years are pronounced like this:

- 1015 (ein)tausendfünfzehn
- 1115 elfhundertfünfzehn
- 1215 zwölfhundertfünfzehn
- 1315 dreizehnhundertfünfzehn
- ...
- 1815 achtzehnhundertfünfzehn
- 1915 neunzehnhundertfünfzehn
- 2015 zweitausendfünfzehn
- 2115 zweitausendeinhundertfünfzehn

Or in words, the numbers are pronounced normally except that from 1100 to 1999, XYAB is pronounced as XY hundert AB.

PS: The English style of pronouncing years is also used occasionally as it is shorter, but it's only borderline correct.

Comment: Additionally, following ponounciations are common:

2015: Zwanzigfünfzehn; 1945: Neuzehnfünfundvierzig; generally, its also common to split the number in two numbers and concatenate them, as long as there is no number <10 involved.

Comment: _2115 zweitausendeinhundertfünfzehn_ We'll see, we'll see..

Comment: @TaW: I agree this must change as the 22nd century approaches, but as it's quite likely that the English style will become standard way before that point anyway, I chose not to mention the fact.

Comment: Rarely, people say "zwotausendfünfzehn" as well.

Comment: @ComFreek: this is another story that has nothing to do with this topic. Zwo is actually only used instead of "zwei" on spelling long numbers - just to prevent one gets it wrong with the similarly sounding "drei"

Comment: In spoken language, people will say "neunzehn-füfnundneunzig" much more often than "neunzenhundert-und-fünfundneunzig". Also, for the 20th century, the century is sometimes ommitted. "Wann wurde Kohl gewählt?" - "Ich glaube, das war 82, und dann bis 98."

Answer (score 9):

The year 1995 is read *neunzehnhundertfünfundneunzig*. You might also hear *neunzehnfünfundneunzig*, but that is more colloquial.

2007 is read as *zweitausendsieben*, although you sometimes hear *zwanzigsieben*.

Comment: More generally, years from 1100 (_elfhundert_) to 1999 are read as hundreds. Years before 1100 are treated like regular numbers.

Comment: Ich habe kein Problem mit zB zehn-sechzig (1060), und bevorzuge idR neunzehn-zwanzig (1920) statt etwa neunzehn-hundert-zwanzig. Ich halte das keineswegs für umgangssprachlich.

Comment: @Ingmar: Ich höre das nie. Muß also irgendwie geographisch oder anderweitig ungleichmäßig verteilt sein.

Comment: My experience is that it is used to distinguish years and numbers. Neunzehnfünfzig is a year, neunzehnhundertfünfzig  is a number.

Comment: @Mr Lister: The usual form for non-year numbers is _tausendneunhundertfünfzig_.

Comment: I've never heard anyone use _zwanzigsieben_ ever. Hearing _neunzehnfünfundneunzig_ is quite rare, usually it's either _neunzehnhundertfünfundneunzig_ or just _fünfundneunzig_ when it's clear from the context which year is meant.

Comment: yes, but _zwanzig-zehn_ or _zwanzig-zwanzig_ are quite common, the former even idiomatic as in _Agenda 2010_..

Comment: Instead of _zwanzig_-X, some people even say _zwei_-X or _zwo_-X, leaving out _tausend_ – just like _hundert_ last century. It saves another precious syllable. Also, two-digit years for the current century or ca. –80 and +20 years are heard sometimes, especially for iconic ones like ’45 and ’68.

Comment: @TaW: You have a point about names like *Agenda 2010* - however, I'm not convinced it can globally said to be "common". As a matter of fact, "Agenda zwanzig-zehn" strikes me as a modern form of "Behördendeutsch", something that could appear in legal documents, and in texts written by the chancellor's spokesperson, but which (at least here in South-Western Germany) hardly ever appears in actual spoken language.

Answer (score 0):

The same pattern holds true for all year-numbers between 1100 and 1999. 
Some examples:

- 1453 "vierzehnhundertdreiundfünfzig",
- 1500 "fünfzehnhundert",
- 1806 "achtzehnhundertsechs".

But 378 "dreihundertachtundsiebzig" and 1077 "eintausendsiebenundsiebzig".

2007 would be "zweitausendsieben" and 2018 "zweitausendachtzehn"

Comment: That doesn't seem to add anything that isn't already covered in another answer, besides the hyphens, which look odd to me. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I answered as per the question, I did not check others.